# How to control ViewGroup childs focus?

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I disable a child from gaining touch input from a ViewGroup?  I can't seem to be able to disable this...

The button keeps getting the pressed events when I press on the ViewGroup.

Any idea how to control the focus and touch events?

I have tried:

```
setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
btn.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Create a custom `ViewGroup`, i.e. `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` and override `dispatchSetPressed(...)` so that the press event doesn't propagate to it's children.

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create your own custom view and override [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) for that ViewGroup to do nothing?

Just an idea :)